# V8 elements kinds optimization

Tags: optimization, v8

After reading this article: https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds, I wondering if `null` and `object` are considered same type by V8 in terms of internal optimizations.

eg.
`[{}, null, {}]` vs `[{}, {}, {}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only types considered for elements kinds are "small integer", "double", and "anything". `null` is not an integer or a double, so it's "anything".

Note that elements kinds are tracked per array, not per element. An array's elements kind is the most generic elements kind required for any of its elements:

```
[1, 2, 3]     // "integer" elements (stored as integers internally)
[1, 2, 3.5]   // "double" elements (stored as doubles: [1.0, 2.0, 3.5])
[1, 2, {}]    // "anything" elements
[1, 2, null]  // "anything" elements
[1, 2, "3"]   // "anything" elements
```

The reason is that the benefit of tracking elements kinds in the first place is that some checks can be avoided. That has significant impact (in relative terms) for operations that are otherwise cheap. For example, if you wanted to sum up an array's elements, which are all integers:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) result += array[i];
```

adding integers is really fast (one instruction + overflow check), so checking for every element "is this element an integer (so I can do an integer addition)?" (another instruction + conditional jump) adds a relatively large overhead, so knowing up front that *every element in this array is an integer* lets the engine skip those checks inside the loop. Whereas if the array contained strings and you wanted to concatenate them all, string concatenation is a much slower operation (you have to allocate a new string object for the result, and then decide whether you want to copy the characters or just refer to the input strings), so the overhead added by an additional "is this element a string (so I can do a string concatenation)?" check is probably barely measurable. So tracking "strings" as an elements kind wouldn't provide much benefit, but would add complexity to the implementation and probably a small performance cost in some situations, so V8 doesn't do it. Similarly, if you knew up front "this array contains only `null`", there isn't anything obvious that you could speed up with that knowledge.

Also: as a JavaScript developer, **don't worry about elements kinds**. See that blog post as a (hopefully interesting) story about the lengths to which V8 goes to squeeze every last bit of performance out of your code; don't specifically contort your code to make better use of it (or spend time worrying about it). The difference is usually small, and in the cases where it does matter, it'll probably happen without you having to think about it.

Comment: Thanks !
Does this rule also apply to function arguments ? (integer/double/anything)

Comment: ... and also function return value ?

Comment: No, function arguments and return values receive no special typing treatment. (And I don't see how they could -- pretty much by definition, callers can pass in anything they want, and callees can return anything they want. An array can track "all elements are integers, whoa now there's a string, update the stored elements kind", but there is no equivalent of that for a function.)